Redshift: Subquery not working, returns error
I am trying to return a list of tables that are not found in table A but are found in table B.
Select tab.table_name
  from information_schema.tables tab
 Where tab.table_name not in (Select tc.table_name from terry.table_count tc);

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong.  This sort of query would work in Oracle but does not seem to work in Redshift.

what error message are you getting?  there are a number of possibilities

Since you haven't answered the question about the error message I'll just take a (well informed) stag at what is happening.  You are getting 'Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables'.
This happens (among other reasons) when you are attempting to access leader-only information from a compute node.  Redshift is a cluster with a leader node that assigns work to the compute nodes and once this work is done recombines results for presentation.  Some database information only lives on the leader and isn't available to compute nodes.
I did a write-up on working around this here - How to join System tables or Information Schema tables with User defined tables in Redshift
